# Disable a form field in a view according to a bool in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

I have an entity that contains a method to determine if I need to disable a field or not.

In my view, I tried this:

```
    <div>{{
        form_widget(form.myValue, {
            'attr': {
                'disabled': form.get('value').isMyValueDisabled(),
                '(...)': '(...)', {# several other attributes #}
            }
        })
    }}</div>
```

But `disabled` attribute on an html field disables my field even if it contains false.

This is a shared form, so I can't create a logic in the `->buildForm()` method of my Type.

Do you have any suggestion to disable my field on the Twig view?

Comment: why don't you simply do an if of your method and display the form ? `{% if form.get('value').isMyValueDisabled() %} {{ form_widget(form.myValue) }} {% else %} {{ form_widget(form.myValue, {
            'attr': {
                'disabled': form.get('value').isMyValueDisabled(),
            }
        }) }} {% endif %} `

Comment: Because there is several attributes to set, it would be bad to copy / paste all of them several times :-) I did'nt copied all of them so I understand your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okey I found a solution :

```
{% if form.get('value').isValueDisabled() %}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#{{ form.value.vars.id }}').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
</script>

{% endif %}
```

If you know a way without JavaScript, I would love to learn it!